# UIScrollView doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

These are my UIViews:

[image]

in my views I have 2 `uitableview`, 2 button.

I always check my UIView's sizes and these are the results:

```
randomPOC[2231:67151] MainView-1060.000000
2018-05-17 10:33:28.812877+0800 randomPOC[2231:67151] ScrollView-1060.000000
2018-05-17 10:33:28.813094+0800 randomPOC[2231:67151] ContentView-1060.000000
```

When my `mainview` , `scroll` and `contentview` have the same sizes, it doesn't scroll.

But when I divide the height into to 2 (height/2) of the `mainview`, it allows me to scroll. which makes me confused how and why.

when I divided the `mainview` height into to 2 it allows me to scroll but it doesn't covers down to the last of the `tableview`.

I need to resize the `mainview` because I need to cover the two(2) `uitableview` that has sometimes more than 1000height.

```
_mainView.frame=CGRectMake(_mainView.frame.origin.x, _mainView.frame.origin.y, _mainView.frame.size.width, uitableview2.height  );
```

Comment: If the scroll view and content sizes are equal, then there’s no need to scroll, so it won’t scroll. And what’s the question?

Comment: @Dopapp i updated the question

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If so can you post the autolayout constraints and also the code if you have made some modifications in VC.

Comment: have you tryed seting contensize to scroll yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has nothing to do with why your UIScrollView doesnt work.
UIScrollView will only scroll if its content size is greater than its frame size.
You should first decide the size of your UIScrollView frame, Than for a Veritical UIScrollView you should assign the content size as follow:
Lets say you have 5 UIView's which have height of 5 dp each, than you should set the UIScrollView height like so:
scrollview.setContentSize(width, 5*5).
Than if the UIScrollView frame height is greater than 25, the UIScrollView will not scroll. 
Else the UIScrollView will scroll.

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by using this resizing the mainview like this instead:

```
_mainView.frame=CGRectMake(_mainView.frame.origin.x, _mainView.frame.origin.y, _mainView.frame.size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height );
```